# Referencing a cloned widgets in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

Right now i have my program to clone widgets. problem i am  facing is i have to get the data from these widgets(particularly from textbox) on my DB end. But once i clone them i am not sure how do i keep trace on them and know which data goes where as these widgets don't have names(i mean the cloned ones)? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025061/gwt-clone-a-widget-using-dom-clone

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your cloned widget holding the key(s) to the displayed data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = new Button("Original"); 
RootPanel.get().add(button);

Element buttonCloneElement = DOM.clone(button.getElement(), true);
Widget buttonClone;

buttonClone = Button.wrap(buttonCloneElement)
```

[GWT Clone a widget using DOM.clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025061/gwt-clone-a-widget-using-dom-clone)