# GWT Clone a widget using DOM.clone

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I wish to programatically clone a widget.  I am able to clone the Element inside the Widget with Dom.clone but I don't seem to be able to create a Widget from this cloned element.  Is this possible?

```
        //somewhere in onModuleLoad()...        
    Button button = new Button("Original"); 
    RootPanel.get().add(button);

    //.....later on...
    Element buttonCloneElement = DOM.clone(button.getElement(), true);
    Widget buttonClone;

    buttonClone = new Button(buttonCloneElement);  //FAIL - No such constructor
    buttonClone.setElement(buttonCloneElement);    //FAIL - No such setter method

    //This may work but looks messy to me
    buttonClone.getElement().setInnerHTML(button.getElement().getInnerHTML()); 

    //add the clone to the root panel??
    RootPanel.get().add(buttonClone);
```

Is there another way of cloning the Widget?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`buttonClone = Button.wrap(buttonCloneElement)`

Comment: I have two ListBox widgets via **UIBinder** *@UiField ListBox lstHeaderSort;@UiField ListBox lstFooterSort; **and I convert as** lstFooterSort = ListBox.wrap(DOM.clone(lstHeaderSort.getElement(), true));* but I got null pointer exception. Why ?