# how do i clone a widget in GWT , any widget not just button?

Tags: gwt, clone, widget

i saw it on here [GWT Clone a widget using DOM.clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025061/gwt-clone-a-widget-using-dom-clone)
but then it had the method Button.wrap , but i dont wanna clone the button
i wanna clone the child elements of horizontalPanel.

im using this to clone the widget but its removing all those handlers and stuff from the cloned widget as its using setElement method , which is just copying the HTML stuff to new HTML ,


`class ClonedWidget extends Widget {
    public ClonedWidget(Element element) {
        setElement(element);
    }
}`

any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no built-in way to clone arbitrary widget.
One way to solve this problem is just to create new widget (in this case some factory method can be helpful).

Also, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884319/clone-a-panel-of-widgets).

Comment: just edited the question , as i said , its removing all those handlers ,

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you need to clone the widget?

Creating a new instance is often the way to go.